# Composer needs to check for PHP.exe?

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install Composer on Windows, and the installation process requires me to locate "php.exe." I ran a search for the program and came up with no results. What should I do? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Have you installed PHP? Composer is written in PHP and so will need it to work. I imagine it would be under something like `C:\Program Files\PHP\bin\php.exe`. Most people reset their user `PATH` so programs can find it automatically - paths on Windows always seem rather fiddlier on Windows than other platforms for some reason. If you have not installed it, [go here](http://windows.php.net/download) and choose the version you are building for. 5.6 is a safe choice if you don't know what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, halfer! This is great information, I'll test this tomorrow.